# Issue with Firebase login

Tags: firebase, firebase-cli

Can someone help me it is my first time using firebase. I have installed node JS, updated my npm and ran `npm install -g firebase-tools` and when i try to login using `firebase login` it gives me this error

```
Visit this URL on this device to log in:
https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?client_id=563584335869-fgrhgmd47bqnekij5i8b5pr03ho849e6.apps.googleusercontent.com&scope=email%20openid%20https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fcloudplatformprojects.readonly%20https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Ffirebase%20https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fcloud-platform&response_type=code&state=618585556&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A9005

Waiting for authentication...

Error: An unexpected error has occurred.
```

Answer (score 0):

Try opening the URL in another browser, it is most likely the browser you are using doesn't support app hooks to invoke the application. Google Chrome is ideal. if this fails there may be a firewall or a plugin interfering.

Answer (score 0):

```
Visit this URL on this device to log in: https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?client_id=563584335869-fgrhgmd47bqnekij5i8b5pr03ho849e6.apps.googleusercontent.com&scope=email%20openid%20https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fcloudplatformprojects.readonly%20https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Ffirebase%20https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fcloud-platform&response_type=code&state=618585556&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A9005
    
    Waiting for authentication...
    
    Error: An unexpected error has occurred.
```

when you facing this error u should add this directory  `C:\Windows\System32` inside
of you **enviroment variable path** than you **good to go**

//This lines goes for who do not know how to go enviroment variable path

Click "Advanced system settings".
Click "Environment Variables".
Under "System Variables", find the PATH variable, select it, and click "Edit". If there is no PATH variable, click "New".
Add your directory to the beginning of the variable value followed by ; (a semicolon). ...
Click "OK".
Restart your terminal.